# Move contents of a child folder if parent has the same name with bash

Tags: linux, bash, tar

When doing tar extract operations sometimes the contents extract directly to the parent folder which is awful since they get all disordered. By example:

```
tar -xzf foo1.tar.gz
```

Extracts:

```
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

The solution to that is to create an specific folder for the tar.gz By example:

```
tar -C foo -xzf foo1.tar.gz
```

Extracts:

```
./foo1/file1
./foo1/file2
./foo1/file3
```

So if I have many .tar.gz to extract I will just do:

```
find -name \*.tar.gz | xargs -n 1 basename -s .tar.gz | xargs -I {} tar -C {} -xzf {}.tar.gz
```

To extract them safely, but with that I'll endup with things like this:

```
./foo3/foo3/file1
./foo3/foo3/file2
./foo3/foo3/file3
```

Is there an automatic way to remove the duplicated child folder with bash for those cases that need it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is the second `foo3` coming from?

Comment: Your code also doesn't seem to work for tar files found in subdirectories, since `basename` removes the directory.

Comment: No I wont work if the .tar.gz are in subdirectories, is not the case.

Comment: Are you asking how to do something different depending on whether the tar file has all the files at top-level, or it has everything in a subdirectory with the same name as the tar file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: You could do `tar -t foo.tar.gz` first, and check whether the first filename starts with `./`, and use `-C` only in that case.

Comment: I tried that in an script, but it's very slow because it has to list all stored files. This is because many .tar.gz files are very heavy

Comment: If you pipe `tar -t` to `head -1`, `tar` should exit pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution

To move files from the child to the toplevel directory:

```
find ! -name . -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I {} sh -c "find {}/{} -maxdepth 1 | xargs -I [] echo \"mv [] {}\""
```

This works because if the child folder doesnt exists find would do nothing:

```
find foo4/foo4 
find: 'foo4/foo4': No such file or directory
```

To remove reapted child directory

```
find ! -name . -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I {} find {}/{} -type d -maxdepth 1 | xargs rmdir
```

I think it did what it was intended for. Disadvantage:

It shows many harmless errors.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of entries in the directory (hint: `dotglob`, `(*)` and `${#var[@]}`), and if the single directory entry has the same name then copy the attributes and move the contents (beware that you may have something in that directory may *also* have the same name), then remove the now-empty directory.

Comment: Could you post a runnable example

Comment: Count it where? He's using `basename`, so there's no directory in the filename after he does that.